# Bash script for automatic overlap merging of respective paired-end reads from samples

Tags: fastq

I have around 300 paired-end files from 150 samples (1 forward and 1 reverse read for each sample). I want to merge (by sequence overlap) respective forward and reverse reads for each of the samples. The samples are named e.g. **SRR2155174_1.fastq SRR2155174_2.fastq SRR2155319_1.fastq SRR2155319_2.fastq.** Can anyone please help me write a bash script to do this?

Comment: Hi @CHANDRA7, we do understand "paired ends", we'd like to know reaad-length, coverage, genome - don't have to but it is polite. HOWEVER, whilst there is serious level coding skill on the site fior e.g. bash/awk and its not hard (even I code this one)... this is not a code writing service and you will need to at least make an attempt at a line of code .I suspect you want to concatenate e.g. `SRR2155174_1.fastq SRR2155174_2.fastq > SRR2155174_12.fastq'. Please at least try (hint a bash do loop) - someone can code the regex part.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/447550/
Michael is telling you basically the same as I did over at biostars.

Comment: Since you have many files it may be helpful to use tools like snakemake to run automatically, although as previous comments said the question has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: Why do you want to concatenate them? That's almost never the right thing to do.

Comment: Respected @DevonRyan , I am doing microbial profiling of metagenomic WGS sequence with metaPhlan software which can't generate contigs. But they can do profiling while we catenate the forward and reverse reads. Due to its short marker sequences it can do profiling from unpaired reads and probably average out. Please check this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/metaphlan-users/aclhwUcgWkk . And please let me know if I have wrong understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your original question mentioned concatenating things, which is not what you want (that would result in all of the reads from the _2 files being after all of those in _1). What you want is to merge overlapping paired end reads. There are a variety of tools available for that, from [flash](https://ccb.jhu.edu/software/FLASH/) to [bbmerge](https://jgi.doe.gov/data-and-tools/bbtools/bb-tools-user-guide/bbmerge-guide/). The general structure then is:

```
for R1 in *_1.fastq ; do
    sampleName=${R1%%_1.fastq}
    some command with ${sampleName}_1.fastq and ${sampleName}_2.fastq producing ${sampleName}.fastq
done
```

You can figure out the `some command ...` portion yourself.